# updateTabItems not working when programmatically generating content?

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I want to build my shinydashboard page programmatically and I also need to programmatically change the page shown, e.g. after successful login. I have closely followed the example in `?updateTabItems` but somehow it appears as if `updateTabItems` does not work when the content is generated programmatically. Here is my code which does not show page2 after pressing the login button.

```
# create ui that is created dynamically from server logic
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "switch tabs"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(sidebarMenuOutput("sidebarMenu"))),
  dashboardBody(uiOutput("body"))
  )

# build ui of login page
uiLogin = function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)
  actionButton( ns("loginButton"), "Login")
}

# server logic of login page
module = function(input, outpust, session) {

  # observe login button
  observeEvent(input$loginButton, {
    updateTabItems(session, "sidebarID", selected = "loginTab")
    cat("trying to switch tab\n")
  })
}

# server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # sidebar menu
  output$sidebarMenu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      id="sidebarID",
      menuItem("Login", tabName = "loginTab", selected=TRUE),
      menuItem("Page 2", tabName = "page2")
    )
  })

  # body
  output$body <- renderUI(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName="loginTab", uiLogin("loginPage")),
      tabItem(tabName="page2", tags$h2("Page 2"))
      )
    )

  # server logic of login page
  callModule(module, "loginPage")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Interestingly, not even the login page is shown upon start, although `selected=TRUE` was set in `tabItem`. My shiny version is 1.2.0 and shinydashboard is on version 0.7.1.
Any suggestions how I can update the view programmatically are much appreciated?

Answer (score 3):

As so often in (my) shiny applications, the problem was in the namespace. Passing the parent session to the module of the login page

```
# server logic of login page
callModule(module, "loginPage", session)
```

and updating the tab item in the proper namespace allows to change the tab

```
# server logic of login page
module = function(input, output, session, parentSession) {
  # observe login button
  observeEvent(input$loginButton, {
    updateTabItems(parentSession, "sidebarID", selected = "loginTab")
  })
}
```

I did not realize that in the example given in `?updateTabItems` the sidebar ID and the module reside in the same namespace, while the namespace was different in my example.